# Calculating Threshold distance between matches calculated using ORB

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, threshold, orb

I am using ORB for comparing features in two images, to find similarity between them. 
`bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)
distance=maches[i].distance`

Is there a way to find threshold distance to comment on how similar the features are?
I check if the distance < threshold_distance then the features are similar else not.

Answer (score 1):

Using a single threshold for this purpose is usually not so robust.

A better approach is to find the shortest distance (d1), and the second shortest distance (d2), and use the ratio.

```
r=d1/d2
```

You want this `r` to be less than a threshold that fits your scenario.

In addition, you may want to limit valid distances using a global threshold just to eliminate junk matches.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you,

```
double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;
for( int i = 0; i < dest1.rows; i++)
{
    double dist = matches12[i].distance;
    if(dist < min_dist)
        min_dist = dist;
    if(dist > max_dist)
        max_dist = dist;
}
printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist);
printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist);
```